# how to show views block that drill down hierarchical terms to nodes

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a hierarchical taxonomy vocabulary Regions which I want to break my nodes down into 'Region > Province > City'.

I have nodes with term reference using [simple hierarchical select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs) forced to deepest level, referencing the Regions taxonomy vocabulary.

Via views I want to create a block, showing:

- Region 1
- Region 2
- Region 3
- and so on

I can only make appear City and when that is clicked it shows the nodes in that city.

What I want is a views block which shows Region (x no. of nodes), which when clicked will make corresponding page show respective Province then City

I have tried solutions [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21459/how-to-show-terms-in-a-views-in-its-hierarchical-structure) but these only seem to show terms, not the nodes.

thank you!