# How to group taxonomy terms by depth in views?

Tags: 8, views, taxonomy-terms

my example taxonomy looks like this:

```
- fruit
 -- apple
 -- orange
 -- banana
- vegetable
 -- carrot
 -- cabbage
```

i want to render a page in views that groups level 1 terms by their parent term, The page should look like:

```
Friut
apple | orange | banana

Vegetable
carrot | cabbage
```

How can i do such grouping?
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21459/how-to-show-terms-in-a-views-in-its-hierarchical-structure